# Не может прочитать запрос

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

Код подключения

```
var pg = require('pg');

var pool = new pg.Pool({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'postgres',
  password: '111111',
  database: 'chat',
  port: '5432'
});

pool.connect(function(err, client, done) {
  console.log(err.message);
  client.query("SELECT id, user_id, name FROM public.chat;", function(err, results) {
    done();
    result = results.rows[1];
  });
});
```

Ошибка:

> result =  client.query('SELECT id, user_id, name FROM public.chat;');
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined

Comment: В приведённом вами коде нет той строки, в которой возникает ошибка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если верить документации, то ваш код будет выглядеть так:

```
var pool = new pg.Pool({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'postgres',
  password: '111111',
  database: 'chat',
  port: '5432'
});

pool.query("SELECT id, user_id, name FROM public.chat", function(err, results) {
    result = results.rows[1];
    pool.end()
  });
});
```

Comment: Правильно написал ты, я так же следовал документации, ошибка оказалась неожиданной. Sergey Gornostaev правильно заметил несоответствие. В итоге, хоть при редактировании я сохранял изменения, они не вносились в файл. Только после перезапуска проэкта я смогу без ошибки запустить сервер и получить ответ с бд.